# how to avoid duplicate record with certain conditon

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

### Heading ##I have a table with data  like below

```
+----+--------+-----------+----------------+
| id |  name  | testfield |     status     |
+----+--------+-----------+----------------+
|  1 | raju   |        11 |         import |
|  1 | raju   |        11 |         ticket |
|  2 | ravi   |        22 |         import |
|  2 | ravi   |        33 |         ticket |
|  3 | ramesh |        44 |         import |
|  3 | ramesh |        44 |         ticket |
|  4 | rahul  |        55 |         import |
|  5 | rudra  |        66 |         import |
+----+--------+-----------+----------------+
```

now i want output like below

```
+----+--------+-----------+----------------+
| id |  name  | testfield |     status     |
+----+--------+-----------+----------------+
|  1 | raju   |        11 |         ticket |
|  2 | ravi   |        33 |         ticket |
|  3 | ramesh |        44 |         ticket |
|  4 | rahul  |        55 |         import |
|  5 | rudra  |        66 |         import |
+----+--------+-----------+----------------+
```

explanation: If I have a row of status 'ticket' for a (id,name)-pair, this row should be selected. If I have a row of status 'import' for a (id,name)-pairbut no row with status 'ticket' for such a (id,name)-pair, the row should be selected.

For example the rows id 1,2 and 3  have status 'ticket' so they should be displayed. The rows with id 4 and 5 do not have a corresponding 'ticket'-row (with same (id,name) values) so 'import' should be displayed.

Comment: what if you have to or more rows with status 'ticket' and the same (name, testfield) pair. Should all of them  be displayed? Same question if status is  'import' and no ticket rows exist for this (name, testfield).

Comment: yes ,what you said is correct

Comment: I did some changes on your post.  Please check it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution based on set operations. From my understanding you have to display all rows that contain a 'ticket' in the status fields and all rows with an 'import' in the status field where there is not a similar row with a 'ticket' in the status field.

```
select id,name,testfield,status  
from mytable
where status='ticket'
union 
select id,name,testfield,status
from mytable where
(id,name) in 
((select id,name
from mytable
where status='import'
)
minus
(select id,name
from mytable
where status='ticket'
)) ;
```

But [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ba39d3/1) does not like it. 
It says

> Oops! Something went wrong. Try it again [...]

Comment: Thank u its very usefull for me, i will get back to u if i have any queries